# Send messages to WhatsApp channel with whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp, whatsapi

As there is no documentations about using API to send messages to Whatsapp channel, i tried this library "whatsapp-web.js" (which uses Puppeteer to run a real instance of Whatsapp Web)  but didn't work for me,.. on the other hand, works perfectly for sending a message to my number .. here's the code:

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');

     client.sendMessage("12xxxxxxxxxxxxx@newsletter", "testtttttttttt");  //id hidden for security
      
});
client.initialize();
```

Is there any solutions or a work-arounds?